# "Converse" to Chinese Remainder Theorem

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-explanation, modular-arithmetic, chinese-remainder-theorem

There are lots of posts on MSE and the web titled "converse to CRT" but this is not the same. The following is from "Multiplicative number theory I: Classical theory" by Hugh L. Montgomery, Robert C. Vaughan:

[image]

In Chinese Remainder Theorem direction is to go from two numbers moduli $q_1$ and $q_2$ to a unique number modulus $q_1q_2$. But this claim of the book is a kind of converse to that. Also it is not of the form $a_1q_2m_1+a_2q_1m_2$ ($m_i$ being reciprocal to $a_i$). I search Internet and worked on it a lot but I can't reach a satisfactory proof for the claim. Anyone knows how $a \mod q_1q_2$ can be written uniquely as $a_1q_2+a_2q_1$?

Comment: [Don't use images to convey critical information not otherwise present in your post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/34123/742).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, this is only true because $q_1$ and $q_2$ are coprime $\iff (q_1,q_2)=1$:
Suppose $\color{red}a \equiv \color{blue}{a_1}q_2+\color{green}{a_2}q_1\equiv \color{blue}{a_3}q_2+\color{green}{a_4}q_1 \pmod{\color{red}{q_1q_2}}$
Then, $\color{red}a \equiv \color{blue}{a_1}q_2\equiv \color{blue}{a_3}q_2 \pmod{\color{red}{q_1}}$
Due to the coprime condition, we have a unique inverse of $q_2$ modulo $q_1$. In other words, $\color{blue}{a_1} \equiv \color{blue}{a_3} \pmod {q_1}$. But since $1\le a_1,a_3\le q_1$, they are equal. Similar argument for $a_2$ and $a_4$.

Comment: So it has nothing to do with CRT?

Comment: Not directly per se, but the "converse" of CRT usually means "if $a \equiv x \pmod{q_1q_2}$, then $a \equiv x \pmod{q_i}$, which is not very strong, but is exactly what I've done (and considered trivial by the book)

Comment: Sorry I forgot one thing that I had in mind when uploading the question: How $a$ can be written as $a_1q_2+a_2q_1$? Said differently: there are $\le q_1q_2$ numbers $a_1q_2+a_2q_1$ considering $1 \le a_i \le q_i$. Are these numbers distinct mod $q_1q_2$? (you proved only the uniqueness)

Comment: There is no need to prove this. Just note that $1\le a_i \le q_i$ allows exactly $q_1q_2$ numbers. So, uniqueness is enough. In other words, $f:\Bbb A_1 \times \Bbb A_2 \to \Bbb A$ is injective, and $|\Bbb A_1 \times \Bbb A_2| = |\Bbb A|$, so it is surjective too.

Comment: Still didn't get it! $a_1q_2+a_2q_1$ ranges from $q_1+q_2$ to $2q_1q_2$ and not from $1$ to $q_1q_2$, so still needs to prove that mod $q_1q_2$ it ranges from $1$ to $q_1q_2$. And maybe some of the numbers when ranged from $q_1+q_2$ to $2q_1q_2$ be equal.

Comment: Actually, $2q_1q_2 - (q_1+q_2) \ge q_1q_2 - 1 \iff (q_1-1)(q_2-1)\ge 0$. However, this is not my argument. If you're familiar with combinatorics, this is just the multiplication principle. $a_1$ can take $q_1$ values, $a_2$ can take $q_2$ possible values, so $(a_1,a_2)$ can take $q_1q_2$ values.

Comment: Sorry, yes, I read again your answer and comments. I got it :)